# how to import data in custom settings from csv file

Tags: customsetting

I have custom setting object and csv file to load data into the object. I tried Data Import wizard but custom setting object does not show up in the list of objects in wizard. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 4):

I found the way, using ApexDataLoader I could import custom setting data.